# ¿Se puede ejecutar "iplot" en VS Code ?¿ O es solo de Anaconda?

Tags: python, vscode, machine-learning

Estoy haciendo un curso y en el curso el profesor, escribe el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cufflinks as cf

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

cf.go_offline()
%matplotlib inline
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

print(dataframe)

dataframe.plot()


dataframe.iplot()
```

El profesor escribe y ejecuta los códigos en Jupyter, pero yo lo hago en VS Code. Y para ejecutar los gráficos, siempre agrego la siguiente línea:

```
plt.show()
```

Entonces, mi código queda asi:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cufflinks as cf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

cf.go_offline()

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

print(dataframe)

dataframe.plot()
plt.show()

dataframe.iplot()
plt.show()
```

El **print(dataframe)** me lo muestra correctamente en la terminal de VS Code.
El **plt.show()**, siguiente al **dataframe.plot()** me lo abre, en no se como se llama, pero me lo muestra bien. Todo bien!

Pero el **iplot** no, al ejecutar el código y realizar lo anterior nombrado se queda un rato aproximadamente unos 4 minutos, y sale lo siguiente en la terminal de VS Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/admin/Desktop/Proyectos/MachineLearningCursoBasico/Seccion8Plotly/Ejemplo.py", line 24, in <module>
    dataframe.iplot()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py", line 1219, in _iplot
    dimensions=dimensions,display_image=kwargs.get('display_image',True))
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py", line 1464, in iplot
    filename=filename)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py", line 135, in iplot
    url = plot(figure_or_data, **plot_options)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py", line 280, in plot
    auto_open=False,
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py", line 1087, in upload
    file_info = _create_or_overwrite_grid(payload)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py", line 1550, in _create_or_overwrite_grid
    res = api_module.create(data)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\grids.py", line 18, in create
    return request("post", url, json=body)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\retrying.py", line 206, in call
    return attempt.get(self._wrap_exception)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\utils.py", line 180, in request
    validate_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\utils.py", line 82, in validate_response
    raise exceptions.PlotlyRequestError(message, status_code, content)
chart_studio.exceptions.PlotlyRequestError: Authentication credentials were not provided.
```

Indague un poco en internet, buscando iplot y entre a este link:
[kite](https://kite.com/python/docs/plotly.offline.iplot)

Intente borrando lo siguiente:

```
dataframe.iplot()
plt.show()
```

Y poniendo lo siguiente:

```
iplot(figure_or_data=dataframe)
```

Pero me sale lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/admin/Desktop/Proyectos/MachineLearningCursoBasico/Seccion8Plotly/Ejemplo.py", line 24, in <module>
    iplot(figure_or_data=dataframe)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\offline\offline.py", line 383, in iplot
    figure = tools.return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py", line 545, in return_figure_from_figure_or_data
    "The `figure_or_data` positional "
_plotly_utils.exceptions.PlotlyError: The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, 
or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure
```

También intenté con:

```
 iplot(dataframe)
```

Pero tampoco hubo caso:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/admin/Desktop/Proyectos/MachineLearningCursoBasico/Seccion8Plotly/Ejemplo.py", line 24, in <module>
    iplot(dataframe)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\offline\offline.py", line 383, in iplot
    figure = tools.return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py", line 545, in return_figure_from_figure_or_data
    "The `figure_or_data` positional "
_plotly_utils.exceptions.PlotlyError: The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, 
or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure
```

Lo que se me ocurre, es que **iplot** no se puede ejecutar en **VS Code** y solo es en **Jupyter**. 
Espero que alguien me pueda decir que estoy haciendo mal, que tengo que agregar, quitar pero siempre en **VS Code**, me es mucho más cómodo estudiar en **Code** que en **Jupyter**.

Comment: el archivo que manejas en vsCode es extension `.py`?, ya que de no ser asi puedes generar otro pero con extension `.ipynb` que es la extension de los notebook y de esta manera ejecutar el servidor jupyter en vscode y trabajar en una notebook desde vsCode

Comment: Es extension `.py`. Mi intención es seguir en VSCode, y al ejecutar el programa que se abra la ventana como cuando era plot. Es decir, no quiero usar Jupyter notebook

Comment: no quieres ejecutar jupyter notebook, o no quieres una notebook en general?, porque como te comento se puede usar una notebook en vscode, si no veo dificil que puedas ejecutar esa linea, ya que hay instrucciones y librerias que solo funcionan en entornos de notebook

Comment: Aaah no tengo idea que seria una notebook en VSCode entonces. Como seria entonces? Y otra consulta, porque con plot se puede y con iplot no? Gracias por tu tiempo que me estas brindando!

Comment: Asi a grandes rasgos una notebook es un documento en el cual puedes poner codigo, texto, imagenes, latex, etc, esta pensada para visualizarse un entorno web, y tiene sus ventajas ya que al trabajar como una terminal, puedes ejecutar codigo linea por linea mientras visualizas la salida, en machine learning es muy util

Comment: ahora, acerca de `iplot` debe ser una instruccion que trabaja solo con `ipython`, se reconocen por la `i` del principio, ipython es la shell sobre la que trabajan las notebooks, y basicamente es la terminal de python pero con funcionalidades añadidas, si quieres ver como se ve una notebook en vsCode crea un archivo y lo guardas con extension `ipynb`, dependiendo de tu compu puede tardar en cargarlo, porque tendra que correr el servidor jupyter (que tienes que tener instalado)

Comment: Okok, entiendo. Y, volviendo a lo de una notebook, me podrias indicar como instalarlo? O si me quieres mandar algun link que recomiendes donde expliquen la instalacion. Y otra cosa, que no se si esta mal decirlo, no queres poner tu respuesta(fuera de los comentarios) para marcarla como mejor respuesta. Ya que me estas ayudando, solucionando el problema y duda, y ademas aconsejando de mas cosas que ni estaban en la pregunta. Digo, no se.

Comment: asi es como se instala jupyter [https://jupyter.org/install], si te funciona lo pongo como respuesta, tu no te preocupes por eso